# Why won't my Google+ photos appear completely in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-plus

After enabling the new photos feature I waited a couple of days to let Google sync my 30K+ photos from Google+ to Google Drive. But now it's stuck for days without any indication of progress. How can I get every photo to Drive? Is there any way to restart this sync or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the feature was announced (http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2015/03/photosindrive.html) it indicated that new photos being uploaded would appear immediately, but that older photos would take longer:

> You’ll start seeing your photos in Drive today—immediately if they’re new, and a few weeks for your entire library—so give it a try, and let us know what you think.

"A few weeks" is pretty vague - the process is still in progress. There is little you can do to force all 50,000 to show up, although doing something with older photos (resharing them to Google+, for example) has sometimes forced those particular ones to sync.

Answer (score 0):

This is long process, think about many millions of users, each of them having at least 1000 photos...

So you should wait

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DaveM, this is the only answer OP can get. As you probably know such migration are normally very stochastic process so probably even Google can't provide him more precise information